# display total and used GB with percentage in one line linux command

Tags: linux, awk, disk-usage

I am trying to get `/dev/sda` output in the following format.

> 20% (10 GB used out of 50 GB).

I tried using:

`df -h /dev/sda3|awk 'NR==2'|awk '{print $5}'`

but it gives me the percentage.
I tried using echo and multiple awk statement, but either the command does not work or does not give desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df -B1G /dev/sda1|awk 'NR==2{print $5,"("$3,"GB used out of",$2,"GB)."}'
```

`-B1G` forces the output to be in GB.  After that it's just a case of plucking out the fields you want.

Slightly prettier code, same result:

```
df -B1G /dev/sda1|awk 'NR==2{printf "%s (%d GB used out of %d GB).\n",$5,$3,$2}'
```

`sed` version:

```
df -B1G /dev/sda1|sed -n 's!^/[^ ]* *\([0-9]*\) *\([0-9]*\) *[0-9]* *\([0-9%]*\).*!\3 (\2 GB used out of \1 GB).!p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Below command

```
df -Ph /dev/sda1|awk 'NR >1{print $(NF-1)"("$3" "  "used out of " " " $2")"}'
```

Command

```
df -Ph /dev/sda1|awk 'NR >1{print $(NF-1)"("$3" "  "used out of " " " $2")"}'

31%(140M used out of  488M)
```